# How to set preparedStatement() value of an auto_increment field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, javadb

Please, I have a table called `sales` which has 6 columns with the first column being set to be `auto_increment`. That is, I have this table;

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
`billno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`item_code` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
`item_name` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`quantity` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
`amount` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`billno`));
```

And now in a Java project, I wanna insert some data into 5 fields not taking into consideration `billno`, since it's an auto_increment column.
I searched for a solution to this on the internet but didn't find anything that worked in my case.

Here's is how I got about this:

```
String query = "insert into sales values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
stmtDue = conn.prepareStatement(query);

stmtDue.setString(1, date);
stmtDue.setInt(2, itemCode);
stmtDue.setString(3, prodName);
stmtDue.setInt(4, quantity);
stmtDue.setInt(5, totalPrice);

int rowset = stmtDue.executeUpdate();
```

This above approach was proposed by [coderanch forum](https://coderanch.com/t/632275/databases/PreparedStatement-Auto-Increment). So when I ran that I got this error message: `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`.

I also tried this:

```
String query = "insert into sales values(DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
stmtDue = conn.prepareStatement(query);

stmtDue.setString(2, date);
stmtDue.setInt(3, itemCode);
stmtDue.setString(4, prodName);
stmtDue.setInt(5, quantity);
stmtDue.setInt(6, totalPrice);
```

That still didn't work.

Please how can I go about solving this issue?

Comment: You could try starting at `0` instead of `1`

Comment: Unfortunately, I using this way, but it didn't work. I still get this `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Answer (score 1):

You should specify which columns you are inserting into:

```
"insert into sales(columnname, columnname, columnname,columnname) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

and leave out the auto increment column. The auto increment will be auto incremented.

Or you can pass in a zero like this:

```
"insert into sales(autoincrementcolumn, columnname, columnname, 
columnname,columnname) values(0, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: I tried that but still did not work. But I get this: `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: can you copy and past exactly what you had tried now?

Comment: you can also pass null or 0 (zero) for the primary key.

Comment: `query = "insert into sales(date, item_code, item_name, quantity, amount) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    stmtDue = conn.prepareStatement(query);

                    stmtDue.setString(1, date);
                    stmtDue.setInt(2, itemCode);
                    stmtDue.setString(3, prodName);
                    stmtDue.setInt(4, quantity);
                    stmtDue.setInt(5, totalPrice);`

Comment: @danielGraham it looks good, not sure. try this "insert into sales(billno, date, item_code, item_name, quantity, amount) values(0,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" and leave the rest as it is.

Comment: Then how do I set them? Do I use : `stmtDue.setString(1, date); stmtDue.setInt(2, itemCode); stmtDue.setString(3, prodName); stmtDue.setInt(4, quantity); stmtDue.setInt(5, totalPrice);` again?

Comment: leave the set as it was. It only sets the question marks.